# How can I undo a commit that solved a conflict issue so that the conflict happens again?

Tags: git, undo

**found it out myself:** git cherry-pick did the trick, simple cherry pick the wanted commit and the both modified status was regained so that I could merge again.

I did a commit with sha `51f1ee0e4ebebf551db20de1aa48badb0259c21b` which was fine. I then pulled from master and a merge conflict happened and I commited the manual merge. I want to undo this. The following, manually merged commit is `ad587bc7ac0d9d23ac77b5611537399bd581004c`.

Basically I want to roll back to `51f1ee0e4ebebf551db20de1aa48badb0259c21b` sothat a merge conflict happens again when I pull sothat I can re-auto merge things and push that.

The commit I want to pull/ merge from is `eedea8c2fe7f0de9d9fe796bb9107a577f9dbb79`

Comment: You can always use `git reset --hard <commit>` to go to any different commit (older or newer), but I'm not sure I'm reading the question well enough to say that that's what you're looking for.

Comment: but when i pull the already commited merge is being pulled, but i want to pull so that a merge conflict happens again

Comment: You mean you pushed the commit corresponding to manual resolution an upstream repository already? If yes, and if you are the only one using that particluar upstream repository, then you can revert back by doing a forced push.

Comment: So you didn't just merge, you also pushed the incorrect merge to the remote?

Comment: yep but i did it with cherry pick thanks :)